# jquery each match not work

Tags: jquery, regex, match, each

In anyway, I want make a judge, if div's id match something, then add class to it. My code here, but each match not work. pls help, thx.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = '3';
    $('.ddd').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id').match(/^'id'+num$/)){
            $(this).addClass('eee');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ddd{float:left;display:block;background:#9FF;width:50px;height:50px;margin:10px;}
.eee{background:#F36!important;}
</style>
<div class="ddd" id="id1"></div>
<div class="ddd" id="id2"></div>
<div class="ddd" id="id3"></div>
<div class="ddd" id="id4"></div>
<div class="ddd" id="id5"></div>
<div class="ddd" id="id6"></div>
<div class="ddd" id="id7"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably listen to all these guys saying that you should use the actual id (`#id`) selector or the attribute (`[attribute=value]`) selector, but to answer your question, I'm going to point out what you did wrong.
When creating "dynamic" regular expressions that need to encapsulate variables in them you should use the `new RegExp` constructor instead of the inline syntax `/rule/`. Moreover, if you just want to test if something mathces a regex, you should probably use the regex's `test` method. :

```
var num = '3';
var regex = new RegExp('^id' + num + '$');
$('.ddd').each(function(){
    if(regex.test($(this).attr('id'))){
        $(this).addClass('eee');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry everyone. But I should correct marked a right answer for a justice, because `id^="id'+num+'"` will also match which id are `id30,id31...` So I still like regex.

Answer (score 3):

### Update:

```
var num = '3';
$('#id' + num).addClass('eee');
```

---

You can simply use [starts with selector `^=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and apply class like this:

```
$('div.ddd[id^="id"]').addClass('eee');
```

This will apply `eee` class to all elements that have an `id` attribute starting with text `id` :)

Comment: but doesn't he just want the third to have the class?

Comment: @Sarfraz, @Royi Namir, sorry for my mistake, I only want match the div match `id + num`(num could be 1 2 or 3... as I did, so only one div would addclass) thanks.

Comment: @Manuel: Not as i see it. OP can tell further :)

Comment: $('div.ddd[id^="id'+num+'"]').addClass('eee');

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = '3';
    $('.ddd').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id').match(/^id[0-9]+$/)){
            $(this).addClass('eee');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = '3';
    $(".ddd[id='id'"+num+"']").addClass('eee');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = '3';
    $('.ddd[id^="id'+num+'"]').addClass('eee');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = '3';
    $('.ddd#id' + num).addClass('eee');
});
```